# Sobrescrever variável assíncrona

Tags: javascript, jquery, assincronismo

Preciso ter controle do número de chamadas assíncronas simultâneas do ajax, porém não consigo sobrescrever a variável de controle que guarda o número dessas chamadas. Toda vez que uma chamada assíncrona é lançada ele usa o valor da primeira chamada (*uma cópia da variável antes da primeira chamada acredito eu*).

Segue meu código:

```
var loaderCallStack = [];
var IsLoaderForSubmit = false;
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').trigger('click');

    IsLoaderForSubmit = false;
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        loaderCallStack.push("handle");
        if (IsLoaderForSubmit)
        {
            //váriaveis que preciso alterar  aqui
        }
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        loaderCallStack.pop();
        if (IsLoaderForSubmit && (loaderCallStack.length === 0))
        {
            //váriaveis que preciso alterar  aqui
            IsLoaderForSubmit = false;
        }
    });
});
```

A minha dúvida é, tenho como controlar o número de chamadas mantendo o código assíncrono? Sei que colocá-lo como síncrono seria uma opção, mas no momento não é o desejado.

A solução que pensei foi empilhar algo toda vez que a chamada é feita e desempilhar quando ela termina. Se dessa meneira com uma variável de controle isso não é possível de ser feito, existe outro jeito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pmargreff, tentei simular o seu problema, notei que o `ajaxStart` é chamado apenas na primeira requisição, então utilize o `ajaxSend`.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/xy3k56jo/1/)

```
var qtdRegistros = 0;    
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    qtdRegistros++;
    if (qtdRegistros> 1) {
        jqXHR.abort();
    }
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    qtdRegistros--;
});
```

*P.S.: Não criei um exemplo direto no SO, pois para simular este problema precisei usar a API do JSFiddle para simular as requisições.*

Comment: Olá, troquei o Start pelo Send e continuei recebendo o mesmo resultado, o problma não é ao detectar o envio, o problema acontece quando tenho mais de um envio simultâneo.

Comment: fiz uma alteração no script, estou abortando o envio caso haja mais de uma requisição.

Comment: funcionou, obrigado.